# Test Coverage with Sonar for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, gallio

I'm using Sonar 3.0.1 with the C-Sharp Plugins Ecosystem plug-in.

When running an analysis with the Simple Java Runner I don't receive any test coverage reports, instead Gallio prints the following error.

> ERROR c.g.TestReportSensor - Source file not found for test report

This file means that if I have file Calc.cs and TestCalc.cs, Gallio cannot find the former and as a result cannot produce any coverage report.

I follow the default test project naming convention and Sonar easily qualify my test project as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, such error means that the assemblies used by Gallio when executing the unit tests were not "freshly" compiled or moved out of the standard "bin/debug" folder before running Sonar.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! The unit tests assemblies are certainly in 'bin/debug'. I wonder about the criterion for 'freshness'. But basically they have been compiled a few minutes before running an analysis. The were compiled on a different machine though...

Comment: Can you compile + run Sonar analysis on the same machine? Because I'm pretty sure this is the root cause of the problem: when you compile in Debug mode, the PDB files store the location of the source code and this info is then used when generating the reports.

Comment: Fabrice, I've just done that and it works! Thanks a lot :)! By the way, do you mean to say that PDB files store absolute paths?

Comment: It seems to me that yes (but I don't have a Windows machine right now to check that). You can open one, you'll quickly have the answer!